# Passing Variable from one textbox to another

Tags: java

I want to pass a value in a textbox in a class into another textbox in another class using java. I have a class called PurchaseSystem and another PaymentSystem and i would like to pass values from PurchaseSystem to PaymentSystem.

```
    private void btnMakePaymentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    String selected;
    new PaymentSystem().setVisible(true);

    PaymentSystem information;

    information = new PaymentSystem();
    information.itemChoosen = txtDisplayItem.getText();
    information.itemPrice = txtDisplayPrice.getSelectedText();
    information.setVisible(true);

}     


public class PaymentSystem extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 public String itemChoosen, itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemSubTotal;
/**
 * Creates new form PaymentSystem
 */
public PaymentSystem() {
    initComponents();

    itemTextBox.setText(itemChoosen);
    priceTextBox.setText(itemPrice);
}
```

This is what i have done so far but the values in the PurchaseSystem class does not appear in the textboxes of the PaymentSystem Class. Kindly help

Comment: Did you declare both of your class as static inner classes?

Comment: @DRastislav I only had a set of public string in the paymentsystem class since am using it to store the values in the purchasesystem class

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add an *update* method for passing values to `PaymentSystem`. Currently you only appear to be setting values for `PaymentSystem` in its constructor. These changes are not reflected simply by assigning the `String` fields `itemChoosen`, `itemPrice`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`setText(itemChoosen)` is called as soon as the `PaymentSystem` Object is created. At that time the String `itemChoosen` is empty.

I would implement a method in `PaymentSystem` to set the text of `itemTextBox`, so you could call that one instead of `information.itemChoosen`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the constructor of the PaymentSystem class as below

```
class PaymentSystem{
    private String itemPrice =null;
    private String itemChoosen  = null;
    public PaymentSystem(String itemChoosen,String itemPrice){
       this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
       this.itemChoosen = itemChoosen;
    }
   //rest of the class
}
```

when initializing the PaymentSystem class pass that two string values. so you can use those values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reason in terms of objects. Not in terms of classes. Each time you're doing `new PaymentSystem()`, you create a new object, which has its own text boxes, different from the text boxes of another PaymentSystem instance.

Let's take an example:

```
Bottle greenBottle = new Bottle(); // creates a first bottle
greenBottle.setMessage("hello");
Bottle redBottle = new Bottle(); // creates another bottle, which can have its own message
System.out.println(redBottle.getMessage());
```

In the above code, `null` will be printed, and not "hello", because you have stored a message in a bottle, and getting a message from another bottle.

If you want to store a message in a bottle and retrieve it later, you need to store the bottle in a variable:

```
private Bottle theBottle;

// in some method:
theBottle = new Bottle(); // creates the bottle
theBottle.setMessage("hello");

// in some other method
System.out.println(theBottle.getMessage()); // displays hello
```